# How to have multiple MLFlow runs in parallel?

Tags: python, pyspark, parallel-processing, mlflow

I'm not very familiar with parallelization in Python and I'm getting an error when trying to train a model on multiple training folds in parallel. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
def train_test_model(fold):
    # here I train the model etc...
    
    # now I want to save the parameters and metrics
    with mlflow.start_run():
        mlflow.log_param("run_name", run_name)
        mlflow.log_param("modeltype", modeltype)
        # and so on...

if __name__=="__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(processes = num_trials)
    # run folds in parallel
    pool.map(lambda fold:train_test_model(fold), folds)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception: Run with UUID 23e9bb6d22674a518e48af9c51252860 is already active. To start a new run, first end the current run with mlflow.end_run(). To start a nested run, call start_run with nested=True
```

The [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run) says that `mlflow.start_run()` starts a new run and makes it active which is the root of my problem. Every thread starts a MLFlow run for its corresponding fold and makes it active while I need the runs to run in parallel i.e. all be active(?) and save parameters/metrics of the corresponding fold. How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe it will be useful for someone else. You can see details with code examples here: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3592